# Creating new SQL table from dplyr object without using R memory

Tags: sql, r, memory, dplyr

I'm using dplyr to do manipulations with a large tables in PostgreSQL. After multiple manipulations I have large *derived table* which I want to save to a new table. The crude solution is to load it into R memory and write to database. This sounds horrible, as the new table is just a CREATE + SQL, produced by dplyr. Is there any way how I could apply CREATE or UPDATE to database dplyr object using build-in functions?

Comment: See `?compute` - that will create a remote table using the query you generated.

Comment: Excellent, I knew you thought about it.

Answer (score 6):

Hoping to gain a few points by converting Hadley's helpful comment into an answer.  Also, I think there may have been some changes that allow `copy_to` to do this as well (at least it appeared to work for me).

```
data(iris)
remoteDb <- src_postgres(dbname="irisDb",host="remoteDB.somewhere.com",
                          port=5432,user="yourUser",password="yourPass")

irisSql <- copy_to(remoteDb,iris,"iris_table",temporary=FALSE)

irsSqlPermanent <- compute(irisSql, name="iris_table_permanent", temporary=FALSE)
```

The first two lines grab the R standard dataset "iris" and set up a connection (to Postgres in this case).

The `copy_to` line takes advantage of what appears to be an undocumented argument `temporary` that allows the data frame to persist in the database (found that one in a bug report).  The `compute` line also works as intended, but I'm not sure it is needed if you use `temporary=FALSE` with `copy_to`.